# Java logic, triangles

Tags: java

Can someone help me understand what is going on inside this nested for loop? I've been having troubles wrapping my head around the logic behind this

```
public class Old {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Run it step-by-step under debugger and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

First for-loop runs 10 times.

Second for-loop runs i times, where i increases by 1 every time the second for-loop has gone through a complete cycle.

The second for-loop has to run through its full cycle before the first loop number is incremented by 1. Since it's limit is `i` which increases by 1 each time, the second for-loop's cycle has to iterate through the contents inside that loop 1 more time than the previous cycle.

During the second for-loop it is printing the asterisk `*`. Notice that `print` and `println` are different in that `println` skips a line after printing whatever is specified inside whereas `print` doesn't make it go to a new line.

So the number of asterisks printed on each line is increased by 1 for every new line. The result would be 10 lines of asterisks where the last line has 10

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********
```